# Should you use a second graphics card to drive your secondary displays if you have one lying around?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Which of these options is a better solution? I am not asking if one should buy a second card, but rather if there is one available for free if you should use it.

- One current gen graphics card connected to 3 displays.
- One current gen card and one last gen card. First card is connected to one primary display. Second card is connected to two secondary displays.

I have used the second solution for many years but I've had a discussion with colleagues that it is no longer the better solution.

Are there any advantages to two cards in this situation?

Comment: The advantage would be less stress on the gpu and better quality and frames but increased power consumption.

Comment: @Valay_17 Is that actually true though? There could be disadvantages with the CPU needing to communicate to two graphics cards instead of one.

Comment: But it also depends on what cpu you are using, say that your cpu doesn’t work at 100% load all the time, adding a slight 1-2% won’t matter much.

Comment: Newer graphic cards should have no problem with 3 monitors.

Comment: @harrymc : not saying that there will be any problem but if the person has a gpu lying around why not use it instead to decrease the load on one gpu so that one can pull more frames or better resolution without significantly high load.

Comment: @Valay_17 SLI is specifically when two cards designed for this purpose (usually the same brand and comparable models) and having specific connectors for this purpose. Some computers can run multiple video cards without SLI and also without many of the benefits. Yes, for a system that supports this, it will essentially give additional video outputs, but will not give better video performance like SLI does.

Comment: @music2myear Extremely sorry for misleading,I will delete that comment.

Answer (score -3):

Graphics cards that have only one video port do not support dual-monitor setups without adding a second card. 
Monitors connect to computers through VGA, DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort and Thunderbolt connections
we can use both the graphics cards but the second card will product some heat in the machine.